# FIWARE: The usage of Identity Management GE

Tags: fiware, filab

I want to use Identity Management - KeyRock GE in the FI-LAB portal (https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/Using-the-FI-LAB-instance). It's said that this GE is already deployed on FI-LAB.
Can I use this GE just to control an access to my application or is there any other usage of this GE?
Also, how will it work (step-by-step) when a registered user wants to login into my application?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. You can use the current instance of the IdM in order to offer you the authentitation and authorization or you can install your own instance of Keyrock. I recommend the first one in which you just need to create an account in the FIWARE Lab and use the keyrock to offer you security access to your applications. I think that you can go to this presentation [Adding Identity Management and Access Control to your applications.](http://www.slideshare.net/flopezaguilar/idm-and-ac) in order to have deep details about the different steps that you have to follow to do the first scenario.